# how to fetch last inserted rows without repetition(on particular id) in jpa

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on jpa . I got a requirement to fetch last 5 recent inserted rows using jpa that too without repetition

For Example:
I have table like this

for example:

```
id |userId| phnNum
---| ---- | -------
1  | 1    |  1234
2  | 1    |  3214
3  | 2    |  7899
4  | 3    |  6789
5  | 2    |  8899
6  | 4    |  6788
7  | 5    |  9874
```

Now I have to fetch 5 records without repetiting userId.

I tried like this

```
List<UserEntity> findFirst5ByOrderByIdDesc();
```

But its giving 1st records from database not recent. I googled to fetch last recent records in jpa. But didn't find any. 
Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can get last id from database. And write hibernate query for get data since that id to (that id-4).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can pull this off just with the method name.
Try an explicit query:

```
@Query("select u from User u 
        where u.id IN (select max(uu.id) from User uu where uu.userId = u.userId) 
        order by u.id desc") 
List<UserEntity> findFirstNByOrderByIdDesc(Pageable pageable);
```

Then call:

```
findFirstNByOrderByIdDesc(new PageRequest(0,5));
```

Comment: I got it with this     List<UserEntity> findFirst5ByStatusOrderByCreateTimeDesc(String status);  but getting only 4 rows from db as there is one duplicate in those 5 rows

Comment: No bro. I asked how to fetch recent 5 records without repetition .

Comment: @PavanAlapati You can modify the above query as `SELECT U1 FROM User U1 WHERE U.id IN = (SELECT DISTINCT U2.userId FROM User U2 ORDER BY U2.createTime DESC)`

Comment: @PavanAlapati In your dataset, all the rows are unique. Based on your goal which i assumed is 'Now I have to fetch 5 records without repetiting userId' i have constructed my query. If this is actually what you are aiming for i have added small update in the correlated subquery. Thanks ansh for the 'IN' spot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

`@Query("from UserEntity u group by u.userId order by u.id desc limit 5)
List<UserEntity> findFirst5ByOrderByIdDesc();`

Or you can pass limit by parameter like this:

`@Query("from UserEntity u group by u.userId order by u.id desc limit = :limit)
List<UserEntity> findFirst5ByOrderByIdDesc(@Param("limit") Long limit);`